# Is database diagram in SQL Server Management Studio considered as ER diagram?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I just have this simple question. in SQL Server Management Studio there is an option Database Diagrams, is it ER diagram ?

Comment: It's the tool "management studio" that does the diagramming not SQL Server (which doesn't really have a UI - only client applications)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do a database diagram.

Expand DataBases --> choose database--> database diagrams --> right click(NEW DB diagram).

Comment: Can you put notes or comments somewhere in this design?

Answer (score 2):

No I believe. 
ER diagram does not refer to relational data model and can be mapped into different data structures.
SQL Server diagram is specific only to relational model and DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server let you create a Physical data model Diagram that could come from a ER Diagram or not. An ER Diagram is more abstract.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram produced by SSMS is not an [Entity Relationship diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model).

It is a very useful tool, and does model the relationships that physically exist between tables, but is missing a few key features of ER diagrams.